# What exactly does the |= operator do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

What exactly does this operator `|=` do?
I have this code for Unity in C#

```
bool shoot = Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1");
shoot |= Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2");
```

Comment: `a |= b` is equal to `a = a | b`. Read from : [`|=` Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx) Next time, please use google first.

Comment: I find that question valid. It's rather difficult to search for "|=" even with a combination of keywords (C#, operator) on Google and finding a good answer for the question.

Comment: A C# developer should have a [list of operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) handy. @LearnCocos2D: For that same reason this question will have little future value.

Comment: Where do we even begin to justify what a programmer "should have" or "should know"?

Comment: At the very basics. SO is not a interactive tutorial site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is an OR assignment operator

is equivalento to:

```
shoot = shoot | Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2");
```

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx

Comment: As your link says: It's __The OR assignment operator__